# ES6 Promise.all() strange resolution of promises array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I have a snippet (below) that will generate requests based on a couple of params. It essentially creates load similar to [JBehaves](http://jbehave.org/) by distinguishing requests per user. For the most part, this works fine. Generation of requests works as expected. The results however are not working as one would expect using `Promise.all()`. Which leads me to my question:

Is there an issue with `Promise.all()`?

The format of the results may look a little wonky in this question but, essentially I'm just creating an array of users (which in itself is just an array of request results).

#### Actual Results

Instead of each object within the array being different, they're all the same. In most case, it appears to be the last object pushed into the array (but I haven't fully confirmed this). This behavior initially lead me to believe there was a scoping issue within my snippet but, I haven't been able to find it :(

```
[
    [{
        hostname: 'google.com',
        headers: [Object],
        path: '/url1/',
        method: 'GET',
        date: 1457395032277,
        status: 200,
        ttfb: 1488
    }, {
        hostname: 'google.com',
        headers: [Object],
        path: '/url1/',
        method: 'GET',
        date: 1457395032277,
        status: 200,
        ttfb: 1488
    }]
]
```

#### Expected Results

I would expect that `Promise.all()` would return a (promise) resolving to an array with multiple objects - each one being different as to reflect the results from each task as defined in `tasks()`.

```
[
    [{
        hostname: 'google.com',
        headers: [Object],
        path: '/url1/',
        method: 'GET',
        date: 1457395032277,
        status: 200,
        ttfb: 1488
    }, {
        hostname: 'bing.com',
        headers: [Object],
        path: '/url2/',
        method: 'GET',
        date: 1457395032280,
        status: 500,
        ttfb: 501
    }]
]
```

#### Code Snippet

If you notice the commented out `console.dir(stats)`: this line spits out the results as expected (different results per task) but, if I slap a `.then()` on the end of the reduce, the array is returned as `Actual Results` (vs. `Expected Results`)

(For brevity, let's assume `request()` returns a promise)

```
'use strict';

const request = require('./request');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = (tests, options) => {
  return Promise.all(users());

  ////////////

  /* generate users */
  function users() {
    let users = [];

    for (let x = options.users; x > 0; x--) {
      /* https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/70#issuecomment-32256273 */
      let user = Promise.reduce(tasks(), (values, task) => {
        return task().then((stats) => {
          // console.dir(stats);
          values.push(stats);
          return values;
        });
      }, []);

      users.push(user);
    };

    return users;
  }

  /* generate requests per user */
  function tasks() {
    let tasks = [];

    for (let id of Object.keys(tests)) {
      for (let x = options.requests; x > 0; x--) {
        let task = () => {
          let delay = options.delay * 1000;
          return Promise.delay(delay).then(() => request(tests[id]));
        };

        tasks.push(task);
      };
    }

    return tasks;
  }
};
```

#### Request Snippet

```
'use strict';

const https = require('follow-redirects').https;
const sprintf = require('util').format;
const Promise = require('bluebird');
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

let request = (req) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let start = Date.now();
    let ttfb;

    let cb = (res) => {
      req.status = res.statusCode;

      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        if (!ttfb) ttfb = Date.now() - start;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        req.ttfb = ttfb;
        req.end = Date.now() - start;
        resolve(req);
      });

      res.on('error', (err) => {
        req.error = err;
        resolve(req);
      });
    };

    /* convert cookies for convenience */
    if (req.headers.cookies) {
      let cookies = [];
      for (let cookie of Object.keys(req.headers.cookies)) {
        cookies.push(sprintf('%s=%s', cookie, req.headers.cookies[cookie]));
      }
      req.headers.cookie = cookies.join('; ');
      req.cookies = req.headers.cookies;
      delete req.headers.cookies;
    }

    https.request(req, cb).end();
  });
};

module.exports = request;
```

#### Using

```
$ npm --version
2.14.12
$ node --version
v0.12.9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please check `console.log("same", values[0] == stats)` (in place of the out-commented `console.dir`? Looks to me like not the last object was pushed multiple times, but rather *the same object* was used.

Comment: Please show us your `request` function. I'll bet on an object that was forgotten to be re-initialised.

Comment: @Bergi The results are ```same false;
same true;
same true;
same true;```

Comment: @Sean3z: As I guessed, your `request` function returns a promise for the same object every time (albeit it mutates the object). Show me it's code and I'll point out the mistake :-)

Comment: @Bergi request script http://pastebin.com/VBJ6Jrgf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an issue with `Promise.all()`?

No.

> Instead of each object within the array being different, they're all the same.

Indeed. They are all the same object.

Your [`request` function](http://pastebin.com/VBJ6Jrgf) does - for whatever reason - resolve its returned promise with its argument. As you are passing the very same `tests[id]` object to all requests of a batch, they all will end up with this object.

Your `console.dir` did show the expected results because `request` does mutate its argument - the test object contains different values after every call, which are subsequently logged, before being overwritten in the next call.

You should change that `cb` to create a new object, instead of mutating `req`:

```
function cb(response) {
  let result = {
    status: response.statusCode
  };

  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    if (!ttfb) ttfb = Date.now() - start;
  });

  response.on('end', () => {
    result.ttfb = ttfb;
    result.end = Date.now() - start;
    resolve(result);
  });

  response.on('error', (err) => {
    result.error = err;
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: You sir, are brilliant! I'm going to do some reading to fully understand what when awry here but, I can't thank you enough!